# How to detect IE Protected Mode using c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, protected-mode

I am building an IE Extension, and I need to keep my Access Database file in the Appdata folder. It's working fine. But in many systems where IE IE Protected Mode is ON, it crashes, I guess this is because IE Protected Mode doesn't allow Extensions to access Appdata. 
I was trying to find a way out so that I can detect if IE is in Protected Mode through my extension.
Please give some code snippets and some links to get me out of this issue.

Regards

I am attaching a screenshot of error as well.
[image]

Comment: i think this is the duplicate of this question..
[How to Access AppData in IE Protected Mode (from a Managed BHO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992765/how-to-access-appdata-in-ie-protected-mode-from-a-managed-bho)

Answer (score 4):

I would use [IEIsProtectedModeProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537316%28VS.85%29.aspx), but you're on your own for interop.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the IE process "Integrity Level". See the official doc here: [Determining Process Integrity Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dse_detil) with a sample in C++, and you will find a sample written in C# here: [Getting Process Integrity Level in Vista using Pinvoke](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/d1437d05-7a3d-4b3f-91cf-a49f45527543)